# Getting Submit button before the looped form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form where I need to input data to store. I used a while loop because I  need to use same code over 4/5 times. The problem is the submit button is coming before the form. It's working. I checked that. But, I need to place the submit button below the form.

I tried to change it up a few times. It still give me the same output.
How to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../sns/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../sns/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../sns/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Department:</th>
        <th>Year:</th>
        <th>Course:</th>
        <th>Date(dd/mm/yyyy):</th>
        <th>Time:</th>
        <th>Roll:</th>        
    </tr>
    <form method="post" style="width: auto;">
        <?php
        $i=0;
        while ($i<5) {
            echo '<tr id="c1">
                <td>
                    <select name="dept'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option value="EEE ">EEE</option>
                        <option value="CSE ">CSE</option>
                        <option value="CE ">CE</option>
                        <option value="ME ">ME</option>
                        <option value="IPE ">IPE</option>
                        <option value="GCE ">GCE</option>
                        <option value="ECE ">ECE</option>
                        <option value="ETE ">ETE</option>
                        <option value="MTE ">MTE</option>
                        <option value="URP ">URP</option>
                        <option value="Arch ">Architecture</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="year'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option value="1">1st</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd</option>
                        <option value="4">4th</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="course'.$i.'" size="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="date'.$i.'" style="width: auto">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="time'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option>9:00</option>
                        <option>10:00</option>
                        <option>2:00</option>
                    </select> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Roll'.$i.'"> 
                </td>
            </tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a table but no rows. If the button is before the form with the code you posted, then you have a float on it or something. Click the `<>` and post the rendered HTML with the CSS used. Also you have `<input ....></button>`

Comment: Why do you need this table for?

Comment: The form is using the row and columns. I didn't write the whole code.

Comment: You also have an infinite loop, `$i` never gets updated.

Comment: I see this rendered when I remove the PHP: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8p0vk6d1/ - we cannot answer your question if you do not post the relevant code. If your button is NOT in a TD then it will be rendered outside the table

Comment: When I replaced the echo inside php tag, some relevant code got deleted. Sorry for that.

I edited the code. Fixed some errors. Still can't get the right result.

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._  As I said: Inside a TD and wrap the table in the form instead of vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the submit button inside a td as well, I also recommend moving the form fully outside of the table as some browser (webkit/chrome mostly) will add or rearrange elements they think are incomplete:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../sns/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../sns/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../sns/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" style="width: auto;">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Department:</th>
        <th>Year:</th>
        <th>Course:</th>
        <th>Date(dd/mm/yyyy):</th>
        <th>Time:</th>
        <th>Roll:</th>
    </tr>

        <?php
        $i=0;
        while ($i<5) {
            echo '<tr id="c1">
                <td>
                    <select name="dept'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option value="EEE ">EEE</option>
                        <option value="CSE ">CSE</option>
                        <option value="CE ">CE</option>
                        <option value="ME ">ME</option>
                        <option value="IPE ">IPE</option>
                        <option value="GCE ">GCE</option>
                        <option value="ECE ">ECE</option>
                        <option value="ETE ">ETE</option>
                        <option value="MTE ">MTE</option>
                        <option value="URP ">URP</option>
                        <option value="Arch ">Architecture</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="year'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option value="1">1st</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd</option>
                        <option value="4">4th</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="course'.$i.'" size="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="date'.$i.'" style="width: auto">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="time'.$i.'" size="1">
                        <option>9:00</option>
                        <option>10:00</option>
                        <option>2:00</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Roll'.$i.'">
                </td>
            </tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="right">
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Renders:
[image]

Comment: As I already commented a while ago. How about voting to close instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" style="width: auto;" action="">
            <table>
                <?php
                $i = 0;
                while ($i <= 5) {
                    #my form
                    if($i == 5)
                        echo '<button class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" style="margin-left: 18%; width: 14%">Submit0</button>';
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" value="Submit1">
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please post comments as to what you "fixed"

Comment: Thanks. I will from now on.

Comment: Please replace the form tag outside the table tag and you have to set a increment option for while loop at end, and yesterday your html code was "echo '<input class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" style="margin-left: 18%; width: 14%">Submit1</button>';" which was wrong, I have resolve with <button class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" style="margin-left: 18%; width: 14%">Submit0</button>'